# Step by Step tutorial to mine RandomJS on Wownero?

Tags: mining, cpu-mining, randomjs, wownero

Is there a step by step guide on how to mine RandomJS on wownero since its the only monero clone that has randomjs implemented as of July 2018.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wownero is using the same PoW as Monero, Cryptonight V7. However, switching to RandomJS is [under consideration](https://github.com/wownero/meta/issues/3).

Answer (score 1):

RandomJS is not used as a proof of work for Wownero.